# How to setup a redirect on s3 bucket only for one file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup a s3 bucket to host my website and setup cloudfront to point to my s3 bucket. All requests are sent to cloudfront will go to my s3 bucket. What I want to do is to setup a redirect rule only apply to one of the file in my s3 bucket. There is a javascript file `/folderA/index.js` in the s3. And I want to apply a rule to redirect the request on this file to another file which is `/folderB/index.js`. How can I set it up? Whether I need to set up on s3 bucket or cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can define a S3 redirect rule for a file. I believe it's at a bucket level.

You can copy `/folderB/index.js` content into `/folderA/index.js` so no redirect is needed.

Alternatively, you can setup a viewer request lambda@edge function that will redirect in case path equals `/folderA/index.js`

something like:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /*
     * Generate HTTP redirect response with 301 status code and Location header.
     */
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const uri = request.uri;
    if (ur.endsWith('/folderA/index.js`) {
      const redirectTo = //where you want to redirect
      console.log(`Redirecting ${uri} with to: ${redirectTo}`);
      const response = {
          status: '301',
          statusDescription: 'Found',
          headers: {
              location: [{
                  key: 'Location',
                  value: redirectTo,
              }],
          },
      };
      callback(null, response);
    } else {
       callback(null, request);
    }

};
```